# Train scikit svm one by one (online or stochastic training)

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I am using scikit library for using svm. I have huge amount of data which I can't read together to give [`fit()` function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit.html#sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit).
I want to give iterate over all my data which is in a file and train svm one by one. Is there any way to do this.  It is not clear form the documentation and in their tutorial they are giving complete data to `fit` at once.
Is there any way to train it one by one (means may be something like calling `fit` for every input pattern of the training data).

Answer (score 15):

Support Vector Machine (at least as implemented in libsvm which scikit-learn is a wrapper of) is fundamentally a batch algorithm: it needs to have access to all the data in memory at once. Hence they are not scalable.

Instead you should use models that support incremental learning with the `partial_fit` method. For instance some linear models such as `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier` support the `partial_fit` method. You can slice your dataset and load it as a sequence of minibatches with shape `(batch_size, n_features)`. `batch_size` can be 1 but is not efficient because the of the python interpreter overhead (+ the data load overhead). So it is recommended to lead samples by minitaches of a least 100.

Comment: I wouldn't say SVMs are a batch method as SGDClassifier is an online implementation ;) of course your statement restricted to LibSVM is true. (it is not even generally true for solvers of the dual QP as LaSVM shows).