# How to overcome SVM memory requirement

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am using the SVM function (LinearSVC) in scikit-learn. My dataset and number of features is quite large, but my PC RAM is insufficient, which causes swapping, slowing things down. Please suggest how I can deal with this (besides increasing RAM).

Comment: Let `n` be the number of your observations and `d` be the number of features. You can either reduce `n` or reduce `d` or both.

Comment: Relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128834/train-scikit-svm-one-by-one-online-or-stochastic-training

Comment: My problem is the large number of features (in order of 10**5)

Answer (score 2):

In short, without reducing the size of your data or increasing the RAM on your machine, you will not be able to use `SVC` here. As implemented in scikit-learn (via [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) wrappers) the algorithm requires seeing all the data at once.

One option for larger datasets is to move to a model that allows online fitting, via the `partial_fit()` method. One example of an online algorithm that is very close to SVC is the Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier, implemented in [`sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html). Through its `partial_fit` method, you can fit your data just a bit at a time, and not encounter the sort of memory issues that you might see in a one-batch algorithm like `SVC`. Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# make some fake data
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000010,
                  random_state=0)

# train on a subset of the data at a time
clf = SGDClassifier()
for i in range(10):
    subset = slice(100000 * i, 100000 * (i + 1))
    clf.partial_fit(X[subset], y[subset], classes=np.unique(y))

# predict on unseen data
y_pred = clf.predict(X[-10:])

print(y_pred)
# [2 0 1 2 2 2 1 0 1 1]

print(y[-10:])
# [2 0 1 2 2 2 1 0 1 1]
```

For more information on using scikit-learn for large datasets, you can check out the [Strategies to scale computationally: bigger data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html) page in the sklearn docs.

Comment: If I understand correctly, SGDClassifier() runs for only 1 iteration or epoch when using partial_fit. I wonder if that will give good accuracy score for my dataset of 3000 samples. My problem comes from the large amount of features (in order of 10^5)

Comment: Are you sure you need an SVM with that many features? In such a high-dimensional space, a simpler model can often perform just as well, at much less complexity. You might also try reducing your data dimensionality, either through something like ``RandomizedPCA`` or through a direct [feature selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) routine.

Comment: I wonder about that myself, but that how it seems to be done in some similar work I refer to. Thanks for the suggestions.