# nltk-trainer re-train classifier

Tags: python, scipy, classification, nltk-trainer

I am trying to see if I can re-train an existing classifier (.pickle file, trained using nltk-trainer) with some newly obtained data.
I've trained the classifier using these links as reference, [[1]](http://streamhacker.com/2010/10/25/training-binary-text-classifiers-nltk-trainer/), [[2]](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/nltk-trainer/latest/nltk-trainer.pdf)

As of now, I am retraining a new classifier on all the data everytime I receive the new training data but this is a cumbersome thing to do since training on the entire dataset again and again is a time and computation expense.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Online models are different from offline ones. Most of the NLTK taggers are offline models. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning. If you would like an "update-able" model, you can try `partial_fit` estimators in scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128834/train-scikit-svm-one-by-one-online-or-stochastic-training too.